# linux file system /dev/input/event4

Tags: python

I have run the code below but I don't understand the result.

Python code:

```
f = open('/dev/input/event4', 'r')
while True:
    print f.read(8)
```

and the result is very weird:

```
>>> 5Q�
>>> 
>>> 5Q
>>> 
>>> 5Q
```

When I press a key, it adds an incomprehensible code. Thank you for help!

Comment: Did you study what the Linux event subsystem *does* at all? Did you try printing the `repr()` instead to visualize the binary byte stream?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.2/Documentation/input/input.txt and http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.2/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt

Comment: If this is a sensible question, it's probably a dup of [python - format of /dev/input/event*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060710/format-of-dev-input-event).