# How to get diff time from kernel input keyboard events(from key pressed to release)?

Tags: python, struct, keyboard-events

I'm trying to write a Python code to capture events from /dev/input/event* on linux.
With the events I want to filter event type, event value, event code and time(tv_sec and tv_usec).

PROBLEM:
With EventType=EV_KEY and Event_Code = 0,1,2 (where 0=key_release,1=key_pressed,2=key_repeat), I want to get DiffTime from key_pressed(code 0) and key_released(code 1) (time_pressed - time_released) even if key is repeated (event code 2).

Any Idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [format of /dev/input/event\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060710/format-of-dev-input-event)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: it looks like a more specific question than the one you've linked.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I agree about the question by itself. But I thought that some answers had the necessary pieces of informations to fix the OP issue. Anyway, you're probably right: so, I've synthesized all of this my best, and posted that as an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, based on [a solution by Treviño](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682549/2363712), here is a quick and (mostly) dirty way to capture keyboard events and report the timings:

```
import struct

FORMAT = 'llHHI'
EVENT_SIZE = struct.calcsize(FORMAT)
EV_KEY = 0x01

KEY_DOWN = 1
KEY_AUTO = 2
KEY_UP = 0

devname = "/dev/input/event0"

def dt(sec_a, usec_a, sec_b, usec_b):
    return (sec_a+usec_a/1000000.) - (sec_b+usec_b/1000000)


with open(devname, "rb") as infile:
    kdtime = {}

    while True:
        event = infile.read(EVENT_SIZE)
        (tv_sec, tv_usec, typ, code, value) = struct.unpack(FORMAT, event)
        if typ == EV_KEY:
            if value == KEY_DOWN:
                kdtime[code] = (tv_sec, tv_usec)
            if value == KEY_UP and code in kdtime:
                print(code, dt(tv_sec, tv_usec, *kdtime[code]))
                del kdtime[code] # Not strictly required
```

---

From [Documentation/input/input.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) events are reported by the kernel as:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

Struct timeval is is its turn defined in [`bits/time.h`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html#index-struct-timeval) as:

```
struct timeval
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;            /* Seconds.  */
    __suseconds_t tv_usec;      /* Microseconds.  */
  };
```

So the corresponding Python struct format for an event is `llHHI`. Once you have that, you mostly have to loop to read events with type `EV_KEY`, then remember key down time, and calculate the key pressed time when you get back the key up code.

Please note that you cannot assume that a key up event match the previous key down event (think about pressing several keys at once). So I keep track of the key code and the corresponding key pressed time in a dictionary. Obviously, you will have to adapt that to your needs. But as I said, this is only a starting point.