# Map stdin from second keyboard to a specific program / tty

Tags: linux

I have a program (a bash script actually - console only) that scans or makes copies, etc based on user input. It asks questions such as how many copies would you like to make, etc and then scans the document, and prints it to another printer.  The program runs in a loop so it's always there when a user passes by, and using a keyboard or number pad you can easily operate it. It basically makes a simple scanner/printer combo into a complex multifunction device.

I can leave it running on a dedicated system just fine, but to save electricity and resources, I would love to have it run on a computer someone else is already using. There is a user who has a laptop on the same desk as the scanner, and I was wanting to have her be able to do her thing in Xorg, as per usual, but have this little program running on an external monitor. That part is easy, but separating input is not. First of all the window has to be in focus, and then any input from the laptop keyboard OR usb keyboard is sent to the program, obviously.

I can think of one way to do this: using virtualbox, I can run a virtual machine without X, have it permanently ssh into the host OS (to which the usb scanner is connected) and I have virtualbox grab the usb keyboard input. But that seems excessive.

Does anyone know of a way to map input from a specific keyboard to a specific program or tty?

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/ http://www.linuxtoys.org/multiseat/multiseat.html etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285716/trapping-second-keyboard-input-in-ubuntu-linux