# How-to intercept keyboard input on linux with a custom daemon?

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, daemon, evdev

I am trying to build a daemon, preferable using Python, which is able to bind to a special keyboard attached to the Linux machine. The special keyboard is a barcode scanner but has an HID interface.

I would like to avoid running X on the machine, so something low-level like `evdev` with its python bindings seem appropriate.

My suggestion would be the following:

1. Use a custom udev rule to generate a character device like `/dev/input/barcode0` and fix the permission to allow the daemon to access the device.
2. Use `evdev` to get the input.

Is this approach feasible? What happens to the keyboard events? Is it possible to consume them so that they are not passed to a running console on the machine?

I have found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285716/trapping-second-keyboard-input-in-ubuntu-linux) here on SO with a similar problem, but it is using an X server which I do not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating HID access with evdev on linux with Python twisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449455/integrating-hid-access-with-evdev-on-linux-with-python-twisted)